# How to generate ultrasound through ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I'm learning ffmpeg recently, and in the process, I thought of a question, can ffmpeg generate ultrasonic and infrasound waves?

If so, is it possible to see the spectrum of ultrasonic or infrasound through ffplay?

Comment: Ask yourself first if your speaker is capable of playing it back.

Comment: Start by generating "normal" sound like a 440 Hz sinusoidal wave. Does this work?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Generating a 440 Hz sine tone is no problem.

Comment: so convert to 40KHz and see if your dog starts barking.

Comment: Related from Electronics SE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156197/can-computer-speakers-emit-ultrasound

Comment: [How to generate a sine wave with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/724391/how-to-generate-a-sine-wave-with-ffmpeg) ; change the frequency to your need, and see what `ffplay` will output. remove C/C++ tags from your question plz, IMHO this question has nothing to do here.

Comment: Nyquist's Theorem applies.  Your sample rate must be >2 x f.  so in the order of 80Ksps for 40KHz ultrasound.  Ultrasound transducers tend to be very narrow range, and you would normally drive them as a single frequency, using an oscillator rather than an audio signal.  You can typically drive one with a square wave switching - throwing a ffmpeg software stack at the problem seems like the long and complicated way around.